# How to fix Reactjs admin and frontend routing with react-router-dom v6 BrowserRouter insted of Switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to build a reactjs website which handle both frontend pages as well as admin end pages. I tried to split admin and frontend components using the following method

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import Customer from "./components/layouts/customer";
import Admin from "./components/layouts/admin";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Customer />} />
        <Route path='admin' element={<Admin />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I wound like to handle all frontend routes by adding routes inside the componet Customer
Also all admin end routes inside the compoent Admin as follows

admin.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard         from '../../screens/admin/dashboard';

const Admin = () => {
    return (

            //  <div>Admin Route</div>  This works , but the below Routes doesnt work


            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className='container-fluid'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <ul className='sidebar-submenu '>
                            <li>
                                <NavLink to='/admin/all-products' activeClassName='active'>All Products</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <NavLink to='/admin/add-product' activeClassName='active'>Create Product</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className='col-md-10 admin-content'>
                            <Routes>
                                <Route exact path='' element={<Dashboard />} />
                            </Routes>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Admin;
```

customer.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter , Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";


import Home         from '../../screens/frontend/home';
import Signin       from '../../screens/frontend/signin';
import Signup       from '../../screens/frontend/signup';

const Customer = () => {
    return (

        //  <div>Frontend Route</div>  This works , but the below Routes doesnt work

        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path='' element={<Home />}  />
                <Route exact path='signin' element={<Signin />}  />
                <Route exact path='signup' element={<Signup />}  />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Customer;
```

http://localhost:3000/admin and http://localhost:3000/  gives blank page I think my inner routes didn't works

I cannot able to add routes inside the inner components, Someone please help me to get rid of this issue?

Comment: No time to really test it, but I think you shouldn’t have BrowserRouter in your inner routes. The router must only appear once, at top level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `react-router-dom` you need only one router providing the routing context to the app, so remove the nested `BrowserRouter` components in `Customer` and `Admin`. Since you are nesting `Route` components then the parent routes need to specify wildcards to they can continue to match rendered nested `Route` components.

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/*' element={<Customer />} />
        <Route path='/admin/*' element={<Admin />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Customer

```
const Customer = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />}  />
      <Route path='/signin' element={<Signin />}  />
      <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup />}  />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Admin

```
const Admin = () => {
  return (
    <div className='container-fluid'>
      <div className='row'>
        <ul className='sidebar-submenu '>
          <li>
            <NavLink to='/admin/all-products' activeClassName='active'>All Products</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to='/admin/add-product' activeClassName='active'>Create Product</NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className='col-md-10 admin-content'>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Dashboard />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-fix-reactjs-admin-and-frontend-routing-with-react-router-dom-v6-browserro]

Comment: One more issue while loading stylesheet. I have imported `import '../../scss/admin.scss';`  in admin.js  but the styles are loading in frontend also. I need those styles to load only on admin routes only. Can you let me know how I can achieve this?

Comment: @Ajith CSS stylesheets are global. You should use unique classnames and ids specific to the admin page, or wrap the admin page in a div/element with an admin id and then specify your admin CSS rules to be descendants of this element.